# Expect an exception or one of its subclasses in Junit Test using @Test annotation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have a test that expects a particular exception, for example:

```
@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void testMyMethod(){
    myMethod();
}
```

The `myMethod()` method actually throws a subclass of `MyException`, lets call it `MySubclassException`.

**Is there anyway to define my test using the `@Test` annotation to accept subclasses of `MyException` as well as the class itself?**

I know that I could simply write the test checking logic myself without using `expected` by catching the exception and setting a flag, but I was wondering whether or not JUnit already supported matching exception subclasses.

Comment: Classic case of user error - the test that prompted this question was failing, not because JUnit wasn't matching the Exception correctly, but because there is a particular case where the exception isn't thrown that needed to be handled within the test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already handled for you by the framework

Let's take a small example (very bad code):
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

```
import org.junit.Test;


public class TestExpect {

@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void test() throws MyException {
    new Foo().foo();
}

}
```

With 2 exception classes MyException and MyExtendedException inheriting from the previous one and a simple Foo class like this one:

```
public class Foo {

public void foo() throws MyException{
    throw new MyExtendedException();
}
}
```

Launching the test using the Eclipse runner prints a green bar because the test raises one instance of Myexception (is a relationship  in POO)

If you prefer to read source code this is an exxcerpt from the Junit source code (ExpectException.java):

```
   @Override
    public void evaluate() throws Exception {
        boolean complete = false;
        try {
            fNext.evaluate();
            complete = true;
        } catch (AssumptionViolatedException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            if (!fExpected.isAssignableFrom(e.getClass())) {
                String message= "Unexpected exception, expected<"
                            + fExpected.getName() + "> but was<"
                            + e.getClass().getName() + ">";
                throw new Exception(message, e);
            }
        }
        if (complete)
            throw new AssertionError("Expected exception: "
                    + fExpected.getName());
    }
```

Comment: I hate @Test(expected=) quite a bit. Main reason being that it's nice for one-liner tests where you know where the exception will come from but as soon as you have two lines and you want to assert that the second line throws the exception, you're SOL.

Answer (score 3):

The test will pass if `MyException` or `MySubclassException` is thrown by `myMethod()`. I tested the concept with this code:

```
public class ExceptionTest {

    private static class ExceptionA extends Exception {

    }

    private static class ExceptionB extends ExceptionA {

    }

    @Test(expected=ExceptionA.class)
    public void test() throws Exception {
        throw new ExceptionB();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [BDD](http://guide.agilealliance.org/guide/gwt.html) Style Solution with [Catch Exception](https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/)

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod() {

    when(foo).myMethod();

    then(caughtException()).isInstanceOf(MyException.class);

}
```

### Dependencies

```
com.googlecode.catch-exception:catch-exception:1.2.0
```